# Hello world cross compiled for ARM is runing on both x86_64 and ARM

Tags: linux, x86, arm, cross-compiling, qemu

I was preparing a demonstration of user mode Qemu's (qemu-user package) qemu-arm. To do so, I used a simple hello world C program `hello.c`:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
        printf("Oi, Qemu!\nPrograma C aqui!\n");
}
```

To cross compile it (statically linked), I used the cross toolchain from `gcc-arm-linux-gnueabihf`:

```sh
$ arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc --version
arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc (Ubuntu 9.3.0-10ubuntu1) 9.3.0
Copyright (C) 2019 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

$ arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc hello.c -o hello_c_static -static
```

The output runs in both qemu-arm, Beaglebone Black ***AND ON THE PC***.

How is it possible?!

### EDIT

About the compiled executable:

```sh
file hello_c_static 
hello_c_static: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, ARM, EABI5 version 1
(GNU/Linux), statically linked,
BuildID[sha1]=6a33aaa5abb9a14fbc0ca4f2e7b432d6fa5d7067, for GNU/Linux 3.2.0,
not stripped
```

Comment: Related Q&A with an answer for Peter Maydell (QEMU developer): [How can QEMU dynamically switch from aarch64 to x86 based on the ELF I'm executing?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76033661) - again `binfmt_misc`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check `ls -l /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc/` to see if your x86 system is set up to transparently run qemu on ARM binaries for you, the same way it can be to run WIINE on Windows executables or whatever using Linux binfmt_misc.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binfmt_misc

Admin guide https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/admin-guide/binfmt-misc.rst

---

The installer for the `qemu-user` package might have registered the executable formats it supports.

With no binfmts registers, you'll just have the `register` and `status` "files".  On my system, WINE and Mono boot scripts have registered handlers so I also see `CLR` and `DOSWin` files.  e.g.

```
$ cat /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc/DOSWin 
enabled
interpreter /usr/bin/wine
flags: 
offset 0
magic 4d5a
```

---

If there's somehow a different mechanism, try using `strace ./some_arm_program` to see what system calls happen when you execute it.

Maybe also suspend it while it's running (control-z) and look at `/proc/$(pidof some_arm_program)/maps` and other files.

(This last section was written after the OP commented that they only saw  `register` and `status` files, not `qemu-arm`, but they've since change their comment.  It looks like binfmt-support is the answer.)

Comment: Seems like you're right! there is a qemu-arm there! How can I undo this? Maybe just removing this file from there?

Comment: @griloHBG: Sure, that might work for one boot; if not read the docs.  You can probably use a systemd command or edit a config file to stop it from re-registering on future boots.  Or probably `echo disabled | sudo tee /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc/status` - on my system that file current reads as `enabled`.  I assume it's a global enable/disable.

Comment: you're right. And, actually, to disable it, `0` must be used, so the command is `echo 0 | sudo tee /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc/status`. Also, disabling it only lasts untill a reboot. And, finally, thank you a lot!

Comment: @griloHBG: Ah right, `0` makes more sense.  Disabled felt like a poor guess as I was typing it. `/proc/sys` doesn't exist on disk, it's just a way for the kernel to expose a config interface.  Manually changing something in `/sys` or `/proc/sys` *never* persists across reboot; it just reflects the default + modifications made at boot time by init scripts / systemd / whatever.  (Usually based on config files in /etc)